# jQuery show/hide: form elements

Tags: jquery, css

I've been able to, in part, get my code working. However, I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the form elements from "animating" when each section of the form is shown. I only want it to fade in/out.

When you click on either Forgot Pin? or Create Pin?, the hidden forms will toggle. Clicking cancel, takes you back to the sign in form.

Here's my code:

```
//click to show Forgot Pin and hide Login forms
jQuery('a.UHF_tabLink_forgotPIN').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.forgotPin').show('slow');
    jQuery('#login').hide();
});

//click to show Login and hide Forgot Pin forms
jQuery('a.UHF_tabLink_cancel').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#login').show('slow');
    jQuery('.forgotPin').hide();
});

//click to show Create Pin and hide Login forms
jQuery('a.UHF_tabLink_createPIN').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.createPin').show('slow');
    jQuery('#login').hide();
});

//click to show Login and hide Create Pin forms
jQuery('a.UHF_tabLink_cancel').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#login').show('slow');
    jQuery('.createPin').hide();
});
```

Here's my POC: http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/3k27g/1/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So use fadeIn() instead of show().

Comment: Of course after I do a little more digging, the responses are exactly what I found and was looking for.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change .show('slow') into .fadeIn('slow'). 
Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'slow'

Change :

`jQuery('#login').show('slow');`

to:

`jQuery('#login').show();`

Comment: OP said he wants a fade effect. This would be an abrupt change.

Comment: He also said he wants to prevent elements from "animating" .

Comment: "I only want it to fade in/out."

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly 
You can change

```
jQuery('.forgotPin').show('slow');
```

to

```
jQuery('.forgotPin').fadeIn('slow');
```

and

```
jQuery('.createPin').show('slow');
```

to

```
jQuery('.createPin').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
jQuery('ele').fadeOut(
    300, //the speed of fade out
    function(){ // callback function after fadeOut is finished
        jQuery('ele').fadeIn(300)
})
```

I've updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3k27g/2